# Kafka Streams: Retries

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka version - 1.0.1
I am getting the following exception at random intervals.  Tried increasing the request.timeout.ms to 5 mins, it's still continued to timeout at random intervals again (few hours).  It's not clear why the exception arises, but the restart seems to recover from where it left, but requires a manual task.  So, tried enabling the retries but that seems no effect, because I don't see any retries in the logs (meaning fails, then attempts first time, fails again, then second time and there on until the max retries).  Can you please shed some light on the below exception and advise on how we can let the Kafka stream application continue to run when this exception occurs, perhaps retry again?  If we need to increase the request.timeout.ms for max value, what is the downside that we need to be aware of, meaning we should not let the thread go on hung state indefinetely when the broker fails?

props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);

```
    2018-07-05 06:04:25 ERROR Housestream:91 - Unknown Exception occurred
    org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [1_1] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key GCB21K1X value [L@5e86f18a timestamp 1530783812110)
    to topic housestream-digitstore-changelog due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 201 record(s) for housestream-digitstore-changelog: 30144 ms has passed since last append.
            at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:118)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:287)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:238)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 201 record(s) for housestream-digitstore-changelog: 30144 ms has passed since last append
```

> Tried increasing the request timeout to max integer value but ran into another Timeout exception.

```
2018-07-05 12:22:15 ERROR Housestream:179 - Unknown Exception occurred
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [1_0] Exception caught while punctuating processor 'validatequote'
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.punctuate(StreamTask.java:267)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PunctuationQueue.mayPunctuate(PunctuationQueue.java:54)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.maybePunctuateSystemTime(StreamTask.java:619)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.punctuate(AssignedTasks.java:430)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.punctuate(TaskManager.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.punctuate(StreamThread.java:969)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:834)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [1_1] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key 32342 value com.int.digital.QUOTE@2c73fa63 timestamp 153083237883) to topic digital_quote due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms..
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:118)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:819)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:760)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:100)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:78)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:113)
        at org.cox.processor.CheckQuote.handleTasks(CheckQuote.java:122)
        at org.cox.processor.CheckQuote$1.punctuate(CheckQuote.java:145)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$4.run(ProcessorNode.java:131)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.punctuate(ProcessorNode.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.punctuate(StreamTask.java:263)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms.
```

Comment: I guess you are hitting a know bug. KIP-91 explains the background: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer

Comment: Hi Matthias, thanks.  Yes, I went through that KIP earlier. However, I am unclear of the workaround, for the above is a known issue.  Please review the above the update to the Timeout.  Kindly suggest the workaround that we can leverage until the KIP materializes.

Comment: We usually recommend to increase `request.timeout.ms`. You have done this already... Hard to tell without a deeper analysis (that I cannot do via SO) what could be the issue and how to resolve it. Maybe seek help on Kafka mailing list or Confluent Community Slack.